# Android app that identify pattern (ex. logo) and nearby area

Tags: java, android, image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition

I'm new to Computer Vision (JAVA as well, but quite pro in OOP), and I have to write android app. 
Whats the main goal of app?

Imagine you have big billboard with some ad. Somewhere in this billboard is placed "special symbol" (icon, logo, etc.) - this "special symbol" is constant and defined/hardcoded in app. I take my phone and points it on billboard.

1) App should recognise this symbol and "lock it", so if I move camera a little bit, the symbol stays recognised (in perfect way: when the symbol is recognised, green border appears, just like in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcyFryRsi4A but for 2D objects).

2) There are many billboards with different ads, and each billboard has this "special symbol". Ads - various, symbol - constant. I need to scan some area near symbol to recognise on which unique ad I am looking at.  App will not be updated frequently, so database of ads should be on some backend.

For better understanding, please see this image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/838/o40c.png/ 
**UPDATE**: I made a mistake in counting steps. Instead of step 4, i used 5. Don't pay attention on it. Just follow the flow =)

All I need is suggestion which libraries/algorithms should I use.

Thank you!

Comment: one suggestion, you should first practice java and oop concepts, then see opencv for recognition part !

Comment: I am pro at Ruby and OOP, but I haven't use Java yet. I need  >>> libraries/algorithms <<<

Comment: First, I am sorry if I disrespected you !

Comment: best solution suited for me- METAIO SDK